# $m=\sum_{k=1}^{2017}k^3\binom{n}{k}$. Find m.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$m=\sum_{k=1}^{2017}k^3\binom{n}{k}$$

Find m.

I was given this question for a math class I'm taking and I don't really know how to start or what identities to use. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Just guessing.  This problem has been around for about ........ 3 years.

Comment: that's nice to know but not particularly helpful.

Comment: Oh, sorry. ${}{}{}$ I'll take a look at the problem ...

Comment: okay, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps try "summation by parts."

Comment: The answer is about $1.5\times 10^{616}$.  Do you want all the digits?

Comment: Let $B_k=\sum_{n=0}^k b_n$, Then
$\sum_{k=0}^K a_k b_k = a_K B_K - \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} B_k(a_{k+1} - a_{k}).$

Comment: @Henry, Just give us the first googol digits.

Comment: Using algorithms described [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) one arrives at $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n-3} n^2 (n+3)$$ So the answer is $$2^{2016}\cdot 5\cdot 101\cdot 2017^2$$

Comment: @Maximilian, Was the assumption that $n=2017$?  Why is this only cubic in $n$?

Comment: @mjw Oh, thank you for noticing that so my idea only works in a special case

Comment: @Maximilian,  Thank you for the reference!  On what page is the algorithm described?

Comment: @mjw The identity can be achieved with Sister Celine's method which is the beginning of chapter 4 of the book

Comment: @Maximilian, Thank you!

Comment: The answer can also be found via the [third raw moment of a binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476676/the-3rd-raw-moment-of-a-binomial-distribution)

Comment: @mjw Comments can only be $600$ characters.  The initial digits are  $1545875211199469217637346652552498435754273200711874270180326958392849660566451611273622755271102924752043069009275611577881608261360780737361931652156082124931665069519972872338274301242692361745334682042476705530541890368019912089543033162690311785536679145367260518026192367176803855553834615853874601661535084420887702557135945138793352126659773370740556906835742421530584139175396254239883061897822869483010739802900460151950378236304463024972104708487 \ldots$

Comment: followed by $\ldots5831991132370853327885621763367107700304042559280805150057006342723622060459952103164497840949540352991917059272424482903842237857789126192503059472981709291520$

Comment: @Henry, okay thanks!  LoL!

Comment: @mjw Coming back to this, I will just remark that this sum became section 5.1 of a [seminar paper](https://vferay.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Teaching/SisterCelineJanischReport.pdf) I wrote some time ago

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to mix up $n$ and $2017$ somehow. We can show
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^nk^3\binom{n}{k}=2^{n-3}n^2(n+3)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
and a special case is evaluating (1) at $n=2\,017$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n}&\color{blue}{k^3\binom{n}{k}}=n\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left((k-1)(k-2)+3(k-1)+1\right)\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=3}^{n}(k-1)(k-2)\binom{n-1}{k-1}
> +3n\sum_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)\binom{n-1}{k-1}+n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=n(n-1)(n-2)\sum_{k=3}^{n}\binom{n-3}{k-3}
> +3n(n-1)\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n-2}{k-2}+n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{5}\\
> &=n(n-1)(n-2)\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-3}{k}
> +3n(n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}+n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\tag{6}\\
> &=n(n-1)(n-2)2^{n-3}+3n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}\tag{7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{n-3}n^2(n+3)}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.
- In (3) we represent $k^2$ as polynomial in $k-1$ and $k-2$ as preparation for the next steps.
- In (4) we multiply out and set the lower limits accordingly skipping zero terms.
- In (5) we repeatedly apply the binomial identity from (2) again.
- In (6) we shift the indices to start with $k=0$.
- In (7) we use the binomial identity $(1+1)^q=2^q$ and simplify the expression in the last step.

Comment: Hi Markus, great answer! It seems [this book](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) might be interesting to you as well

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Thanks Maximilian and yes, it is interesting to me. In fact I've a copy on my shelf. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_k(n) = \sum_{j=0}^k \begin{pmatrix} n \\ j \end{pmatrix}.$

$$m = 2017^3 - \sum_{k=0}^{2016} B_k(n) (3k^2 + 3k + 1).$$

Now sum by parts another couple of times ...

Comment: I think the $k$ in the summand should be $j$

Comment: Right!  Thanks! ${}$ Made that change.