# Cubic expectation of peanuts on squares

Tags: probability, statistics

> There are 9 squares on the table, and we drop 9 peanuts to the table one at a time. Each peanut fall into every square with equal probability 1/9. After dropping all peanuts, we denote $x_{i}$ as the number of peanuts on the i-th square, i=1,2,3...9, and define Y = $x_{1}^{3}+x_{2}^{3}+...+x_{9}^{3}$. Calculate expectation of Y.

**Updates:**

Based on linearity of expectation, permutation symmetry of $x_{i}$ and $x_{i}$ obeys Binomial distribution

$$E[Y]=\sum_{i=1}^{9}{E[X_{i}^3]}=\sum_{i=1}^{9}{n(n-1)(n-2)p^3+3n(n-1)p^2+np}$$

Given n=9 and p=1/9 for binomial distribution, we can derive:

$$E[Y]=9*(4+29/81)=39\frac{2}{9}$$

This answer should lie between $Y_{min}=9$ and $Y_{max}=9^3=729$.

For third order moment of binomial distribution, refer to [The 3rd raw moment of a binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476676/the-3rd-raw-moment-of-a-binomial-distribution)

Comment: "Brute force"... of an (electronic) computer, not by a human...

Comment: You can find $E[X_i^3]$ for each $i$ and add them up, since each $X_i$ is a binomial random variable

Comment: But $x_{i}$ is dependent, they sum up to 9.

Comment: @YuanJi We don't need independence to apply the linearity of expectation.

Comment: Any reason why $E[X_1]$ would be different than $E[X_2]$?

Comment: @YuanJi I know it feels like they are dependent, but this is one of the wonderful things about the linearity of expectation. $E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$ no matter what. Its almost magical.

Comment: I got that, I will compute this expectation.

Comment: This Question showed up in the Close Review queue, perhaps because in its present form it is not certain what is being asked (since the OP has made so much progress).  However the OP's most recent Comment ("I will compute this expectation") would likely result either in a good self-Answer or a more precise formulation of what help is still needed.  I'm voting to Leave Open.

Comment: @hardmath It resulted in a self-answer, good decision indeed.

Comment: @hardmath: Yes, You can do the rolling back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on linearity of expectation, permutation symmetry of $x_{i}$ and $x_{i}$ obeys Binomial distribution

$$E[Y]=\sum_{i=1}^{9}{E[X_{i}^3]}=\sum_{i=1}^{9}{n(n-1)(n-2)p^3+3n(n-1)p^2+np}$$

Given n=9 and p=1/9 for binomial distribution, we can derive:

$$E[Y]=9*(4+29/81)=39\frac{2}{9}$$

This answer satisfy $Y_{min}=9<E[Y]<Y_{max}=9^3=729$.

For third order moment of binomial distribution, refer to [The 3rd raw moment of a binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476676/the-3rd-raw-moment-of-a-binomial-distribution)